# Trouble opening Disk Manager in Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: windows, 12.10

I have two disks, a SSD with my Windows 7 installation and a mechanical disk with my Ubuntu 32-bit installation.

After deciding to install Ubuntu 12.10 alongside my Windows 7 installation I opened the Disk Manager in Windows and shrunk my secondary drive with 30GB.

Then I installed Ubuntu through the *install alongside Windows* option.

After deciding to upgrade my Ubuntu installation to 64-bit, I decided to remove it from the disk manager. The problem is that now the **Disk Manager** won't open. The status is "Connecting to the service Virtual Disk Service". (Translated from Swedish)

Anyone have any idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the Windows Disk Manager software; there isn't much that you can do, or Ubuntu can do here. Report the problem to Microsoft and hope they can fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MS forums, there seems to be several things that can cause this issue, so it's hard to know for sure what's going on, but I think the problem here was caused by the way you installed Ubuntu. If you shrink the Windows partition with disk manager first, you don't want to choose *install alongside windows*. I believe that shrinks the Windows partition again, leaving the other space unused. I suspect either the Windows partition is now too small (Windows 7 seems to need 40 GB) or file corruption is causing Windows to see the disk as damaged.

You might try booting from a live cd/usb and use gparted to delete everything but the Windows partition. Boot into Windows (you will probably need to restore the Windows mbr with a restore disk. Google that if you don't know how, it's easy.), then run chkdsk. When reinstalling Ubuntu, choose the option to use the available space (easy) or use the partitioner to create the partitioning scheme you want in the empty space first (much more advanced if you haven't done it before).

If disk manager still does not open after running chkdsk, use the live distro to expand the size of the Windows partition, probably to fill the entire disk. When reinstalling Ubuntu after this you can use the Install Alongside option.